# Find where an error occurred in a bunch of command line scripts

Tags: scripting, debugging

I have been using my intuition to solve errors in my *Mathematica* scripts. But when calculations got more complex and I started getting errors involving code in more participating scripts (a script needs another one which needs another one, etc.), I searched for a way to find a *file* and *line number* or something and I found:

[How to find line where error occurred in Mathematica notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362170/how-to-find-line-where-error-occurred-in-mathematica-notebook)

and

[The clearest way to represent Mathematica's evaluation sequence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence)

both of them more appropriate to the notebook (UI) environment. I can probably use a notebook and try to run my script there; but I wonder if there is a better way to work purely command line.

Any ideas?

(I am using *Mathematica* version 9)

Comment: If you want to work under CLI, one way to debug is to insert `Print["your label"]` at the place you're interested in. If you want to find a *file* where the current function is defined in, you may need `Trace`-family (*e.g.* `TraceScan`).

Comment: btw. I think it will describe the question better if you state in the title that you are doing the debug *under command line*.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. But when you start having more participating scripts and/or logic gets more elaborated, it becomes harder... Sad that _Mathematica_ does not have "exceptions" but the messaging approach.

Comment: There are functions like `Assert`, `Check`, etc. might help you beyond the `Print` approach.

Comment: Possibly related: [(3837)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3837)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You surely can remember Everything on the site! :D

Comment: I've seen that @Mr.Wizard, so the parser keeps line numbers. However, once running, they are not available. I see that this could help if one runs Trace on top and use the above, but that is beyond my skills/time at the moment :)

Comment: Maybe you'll want to try the method I demonstrated in the *example* part at the end of the question [(26056)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26056/17). The trace result is exported to a plaintext file, then you can use whatever editor you like to investigate it.

Comment: @Silvia, thanks. I found the issue with few `Print` statements here and there as you suggested. But I add that this suggestion seems even better and I will give it a go.

Comment: @caya Glad I can help!