# Looking for the equivalent of C's __LINE__, etc

Tags: programming, debugging

Some languages provide maintainable ways to specify the number of "the current line".  In C, for example, one can use the `__LINE__` macro.

Does *Mathematica* have anything like that?

---

EDIT:  ***Of course***, this is not to be used in notebooks, but rather in `*.m` files.

Comment: How do you plan to use such a macro?

Comment: @Shadowray: it doesn't need to be a macro.  I want to use it to facilitate debugging-via-print-statement (I can't afford WR's fancy Workbench).

Comment: @kjo Workbench is now a free plugin for Eclipse. Everyone can afford it. http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/963774

Comment: @GustavoDelfino: Thanks, that's good to know.  In the short term, though, I need to debug some stuff now, and would prefer not to have to install & learn Eclipse in order to do it.

Comment: Mathematica has no concept of "lines" in the same way as compiled languages do. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/finding-a-specific-line-in-a-package) for an explanation by Leonid. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78067/how-to-find-out-where-an-error-occurs) for some useful debugging tools. Alternatively use `Assert` or stack printing to help you figure out what's going on.